# jmeter shows error, but no errors in resuls tree

Tags: jmeter

Running jmeter 3.  When I execute a set of http requests,
The aggregate graph display shows error:
[image]

but the results tree shows all requests completed successfully.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from [JMeter version 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) the maximum amount of sample results [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener can display is limited to `500`. So if you have > 500 sample results in .jtl file it might be the case that failed samplers were discarded.

Try adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

and restarting JMeter. Then open .jtl results file in View Results Tree listener - you should see all the results including failed ones.

See [JMeter Properties Reference - Miscellaneous configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) for more details.